# Как отправить html форму на стороне сервера post запросом?

Tags: python, django, yandex-money

Помогите пожалуйста, не могу долгие дни найти как это делается.
У меня есть форма:

```
    <form method="POST" action="https://money.yandex.ru/quickpay/confirm.xml">

        <input type="hidden" name="receiver" value="410019188000000">

        <input type="hidden" name="successURL" value="https://vk.com/" %}">

        <input type="hidden" name="quickpay-form" value="shop">

        <input type="hidden" name="targets" value="За добротный контент, ура!">

        <input type="hidden" name="sum" value="15" data-type="number">

        <label><input type="radio" class="hide" name="paymentType" value="AC" checked>Банковской картой</label>

        <input id="input_auto_click" type="submit" value="Перевести">

    </form>
```

Как мне отправить её на `python` без использования шаблона, т.е. на стороне сервака (пс после отправки нужно перейти по ссылке action)?

Буду очень благодарен за помощь :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не уверен, есть ли у Django свои средства отправки POST-запросов, но они есть в модуле `requests` (`pip install requests`)

```
import requests

data = {
    "receiver": "410019188000000",
    "successURL": "https://vk.com/",
    "quickpay-form": "shop",
    "targets": "За добротный контент, ура!",
    "sum": 15,
    "paymentType": "AC",
}

# Результат выполнения запроса желательно сохранить переменную, т.к. он содержит информацию об ответе сервера на запрос
r = requests.post("https://money.yandex.ru/quickpay/confirm.xml", data=data)
```

Comment: благодарю за ответ, но выдаёт ошибку: ```Exception Value:  Response' object has no attribute 'get```

Comment: @Леонид ошибки действительно могут быть. Возможно, это связано с тем, что request не имитирует браузер, а лишь отправляет данные. Как правило, в интернет-банках (а Я.Деньги является интернет-банком) более жесткие требования к подобным запросам. Нужно предоставлять больше информации в `data`

Answer (score 0):

как-то так

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    receiver = form.cleaned_data.get("receiver")
```

и также с другими полями